# Text to binary converter in php

Tags: php, text, binary, converters

I am creating a facebook bot and I want to implement a command which converts a text string in a binary string using the asciii table.
I am using this code, but it's incorrect in fact the binary string which the code produces it's wrong.
This is a portion of the facebook bot code where the variable called $text is the message which the users send to the bot

```
elseif(strpos($text, "binary") !== false)
{
    $binario = unpack('H*', substr($text,8));
    $response = substr($text,8) . " in binary is: " . base_convert($binario[1], 16, 2);
}
```

Comment: You can show some example of `$text`?

Comment: @Iwan `$text = "binary {word to be converted}";` this is an example. In the code above I wrote `substr($text,**8**)` because I am italian and "binary" in italian has an extra character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function [`ord`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php):

```
$text = "binary hello";
if (strpos($text, "binary") !== false) {
    $str = substr($text, 7);
    $response = $str." in binary is: ";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) { 
        $response .= sprintf("%08d ", decbin( ord($str[$i]) ));
    }

    echo $response."\n"; //01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111
}
```

[live](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2771b00f6eba5d2c775e13650ad0eddadf76204c)

Comment: but I want to use the asciii table and hello in binary is: 01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 where every character is represented by 8 bits